# Reset Styles in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2016

Is there a way to reset the Styles in Word 2016 to the factory defaults?

I once edited a LibreOffice-created document in Word 2016 on my computer, and ever since then my Heading 2 and Heading 3 in the default template are big and bold - not the same small blue Styles as when I first installed it.  I want to go back to those styles without having to manually go through all the styles settings and tweak each one to make sure everything is back to the default.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

MS Word have a default template used when creating new documents. It's named 'Normal.dotm' and located in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` folder. Just delete it and restart Word. On the next start, the 'default' default template will be generated.

The [official help article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea) says this as well:

> NOTE: If Normal.dotm is renamed, damaged, or moved, Word automatically creates a new version (which uses the original default settings) the next time that you start Word. The new version will not include any of the customizations that you made to the version that you renamed or moved.

Comment: Doesn't reset the styles for me. I still have the new broken ones. It also seems to be on a per document basis